# How to retrieve the value and id of radiobutton when clicked, in a kendo tree view?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

```
@(
                 Html.Kendo().TreeView()
                 .Name("x")
                 .TemplateId("treeview-template")
                 .BindTo(Model.x)
            )
            <script id="treeview-template" type="text/kendo-ui-template">
                <input type='radio' data-bind="value: textValue,checked:checkedvalue" name='y'>&nbsp;#:item.text #</input>
            </script>
```

> The above code is a kendo tree view which has a list of radio buttons against each item.
>   I need to retrieve the name and id of the radio button.
>
> > Also, i need to bind the value of the radio button to a model for retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different events of treeview like select , change. Following is one of the example.

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                function onSelect(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Selecting: " + this.text(e.node));
                }

                function onCheck(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Checkbox changed :: " + this.text(e.node));
                }

                function onChange(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Selection changed");
                }

                function onCollapse(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Collapsing " + this.text(e.node));
                }

                function onExpand(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Expanding " + this.text(e.node));
                }

                function onDragStart(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Started dragging " + this.text(e.sourceNode));
                }

                function onDrag(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Dragging " + this.text(e.sourceNode));
                }

                function onDrop(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log(
                    "Dropped " + this.text(e.sourceNode) +
                    " (" + (e.valid ? "valid" : "invalid") + ")"
                    );
                }

                function onDragEnd(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Finished dragging " + this.text(e.sourceNode));
                }

                function onNavigate(e) {
                    kendoConsole.log("Navigate " + this.text(e.node));
                }

                $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                    checkboxes: true,
                    dataSource: [
                        { text: "Furniture", expanded: true, items: [
                            { text: "Tables & Chairs" },
                            { text: "Sofas" },
                            { text: "Occasional Furniture" }
                        ] },
                        { text: "Decor", items: [
                            { text: "Bed Linen" },
                            { text: "Curtains & Blinds" },
                            { text: "Carpets" }
                        ] },
                        { text: "Storage" }
                    ],
                    select: onSelect,
                    check: onCheck,
                    change: onChange,
                    collapse: onCollapse,
                    expand: onExpand,
                    dragAndDrop: true,
                    /* drag & drop events */
                    dragstart: onDragStart,
                    drag: onDrag,
                    drop: onDrop,
                    dragend: onDragEnd,
                    navigate: onNavigate
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: I tried working on the same lines but could not arrive at the solution. My question focuses on the binding and retrieval of a radio button in particular.

Comment: Use of Radio Button in TreeView is not a good idea as once the radio button is selected it cant be unselected. You can use checkbox instead which will be more logical.

Comment: It is right that checkboxes suit better in most scenarios, but the requirement demands that atleast a single value has to be selected and they have to be singular unlike in checkboxes where multiple selections are allowed.